# WPF DateGrid: How to bind a column of ComboBox plus need to enable/disable entries dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

This part is ready and operational:

"How to bind a column of ComboBox"

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bot Plate Thickness">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SteelThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding BottomPlateThickness, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And this is the relevant part of my model:

```
public class GridModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _BottomPlateThickness;
    public  string  BottomPlateThickness
    {
        get
        {
            return _BottomPlateThickness;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_BottomPlateThickness != value)
            {
                _BottomPlateThickness = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("BottomPlateThickness");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is another part:

```
public List<string> SteelThickness { get; set; }

SteelThickness = new List<string> { "0.3750", "0.4375", "0.5000", "0.6250", "0.7500", "0.8650", "1.0000" };
```

As you can see, the ComboBox contents are based on a static list. I read that in order to be able to be turned on/off, I have to base that column on an `ObservableList<object>`.

TIA.

Comment: I don't understand ... do you mean, bind "BottomPlateThickness" to the selected combo box row?

Comment: Exactly. BTW: It is bound to a COLUMN, not row. It is working perfectly, but I need to add the ability to enable/disable.

Comment: I am having troubles understanding what are you asking for :\

Comment: I have the feeling that I will need a *nested class* inside my model.

Comment: If you have a property `Enabled`, then couldn't you just use `<ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" ...` ?

Comment: This screenshot should provide better understanding of the problem: (http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/Disable-Inside-Combo-Inside-Column.png)

Comment: That is a really good suggestion, McGarnage. I will try it. So what you are saying is that my "small" model does not have to be somehow inside (nested?) the "bigger" model.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple... you don't access a `ComboBox` in a specific row of a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Why do so many people want to use WPF like WinForms?... it's *not* WinForms. I say this line so much that I'm starting to feel like a preacher... WPF is a data-centric language... that means that we manipulate *data objects*, not *UI objects*. Why not make your life easier and *hold the metaphoric hammer by the handle instead of the head*?

Thinking of this problem in terms of *data*, we have a collection of data objects. One object is represented by one row in the `DataGrid`, so one property of these objects will relate to the selected item from the `ComboBox`es in question. Now if you were to make your life really easy, you'd add a new collection property into that class that you could bind to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property.

Now, to change the possible options in each `ComboBox`, all you need to do is to change the items in that collection property in your data bound object. You could define your 'unfiltered' collection in your data type as a `static` variable that each instance could share:

```
private static ObservableCollection<string> steelThickness = new 
    ObservableCollection<string> { "0.3750", "0.4375", "0.5000", "0.6250", "0.7500", 
    "0.8650", "1.0000" };

public ObservableCollection<string> ComboBoxItemsSource
{
    get { return new ObservableCollection<string>(
        steelThickness.Where(item => item.MeetsCertainCriteria(item))); }
}

private bool MeetsCertainCriteria(string item)
{
    // return true or false for each item to adjust the members in the collection
    // based on whatever your condition is
    if ( ... ) return true;
    return false;
}
```

The only points to note with this set up is that you'll have to manually call `NotifyPropertyChange("ComboBoxItemsSource")` when the collection is updated and that you'll need to use a `OneWay Binding` because it has no setter. Now, wasn't that easier?

Comment: "Why do so many people want to use WPF like WinForms?" I am a newbie. Have never used WinForms. WPF is my first Windows GUI environment.