# WPF DataGrid: How do I access a ComboBox in a specific row of a DataGridTemplateColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

My app correctly populates a DataGrid column with ComboBoxes, using the following XAML code:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Thickness">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SteelThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding BottomPlateThickness, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I am trying to figure out an expression such as

`ComboBox cmb = dataGrid[i].Column[11].ComboBox`

which will retrieve one ComboBox at a time.

TIA

Comment: You are not supposed to access DataTemplate controls like that, what are you trying to do? as there is most likely a better way to achive your goal

Comment: I am trying to debug my code, and inspect to see whether the item chosen with the ComboBox is actually the SelectedItem.

Comment: sa_ddam213: Since you are clearly knowledgeable, could you please take a look at my bigger problem? URL: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249889/wpf-dategrid-how-to-bind-a-column-of-combobox-plus-need-to-enable-disable-entri)

Comment: Note: The XAML code was taken from here: (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19493.wpf-best-combobox-tutorial-ever.aspx), Example No. 9. That demo works quite well.

Comment: Give it a x:Name and access it from code behind.

Comment: I have answered your 'other' question (linked above). If that answer is acceptable, perhaps you could delete this misleading question?

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, Sheridan! Being lazy (aka efficient :-) I was hoping for an easy expression in this post. However, the code provided by ethicallogics below is very educational to newbies like present company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi after going through your question I decided to write a helper class for accesing Rows and columns by indices.I am trying to give an idea . I have not tested it well so there might be some issues.

> > Complete solution [accessing datagrid row and column through indices](https://datagridas2dmatrix.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/accesing-wpf-datagrid-rows-and-columns-through-index/)

**//This class will help to get Row, Column or Cell by indices**. Though there might not be some proper check for null and indices Sorry for that.I will update it later.

```
    public static class DataGridExtension
{
    public static DataGridColumn GetColumnByIndices(this DataGrid dataGrid, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        ValidateParameters(dataGrid, rowIndex, columnIndex);

        var row = dataGrid.GetRowByIndex(rowIndex);

        if (row != null)
            return row.GetRowColumnByIndex(columnIndex);

        return null;
    }

    public static DataGridCell GetCellByIndices(this DataGrid dataGrid, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        ValidateParameters(dataGrid, rowIndex, columnIndex);

        var row = dataGrid.GetRowByIndex(rowIndex);

        if (row != null)
            return row.GetRowCellByColumnIndex(columnIndex);

        return null;
    }

    //TODO:Validate RowIndex
    public static DataGridRow GetRowByIndex(this DataGrid dataGrid, int rowIndex)
    {
        if (dataGrid == null)
            return null;

        return (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator
                                                       .ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex);    
    }

    //TODO:Validate ColumnIndex
    public static DataGridColumn GetRowColumnByIndex(this DataGridRow row, int columnIndex)
    {
        if (row != null)
        {
            var cell=GetRowCellByColumnIndex(row, columnIndex);

            if(cell!=null)
                return cell.Column;
        }

        return null;
    }

    //TODO:Validate ColumnIndex
    public static DataGridCell GetRowCellByColumnIndex(this DataGridRow row, int columnIndex)
    {
        if (row != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter cellPresenter = row.GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>();

            if (cellPresenter != null)
                return ((DataGridCell)cellPresenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex));
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static void ValidateParameters(DataGrid dataGrid,int rowIndex,int columnIndex)
    {
        if (dataGrid == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("datagrid is null");
        if (rowIndex >= dataGrid.Items.Count)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("rowIndex out of Index");
        if (columnIndex >= dataGrid.Columns.Count)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("columnIndex out of Index");
    }
}
```

****//This Class will help to find the VisualChild ****

```
public static class VisualHelper
{
    public static T GetVisualChild<T>(this Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);

        for (int index = 0; index < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); index++)
        {
            Visual visualChild = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, index);
            child = visualChild as T;

            if (child == null)
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(visualChild);//Find Recursively

            if (child != null)
                break;
        }
        return child;
    }
}
```

**Now you can use these classes to get Columns,Cells,Rows by Index like**

```
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Now we can get Column like this.
        var column = dataGrid.GetColumnByIndices(1, 1);

        //As SO want to find the ComboBox within that Column 
        ComboBox comboBox;
        var cell = dataGrid.GetCellByIndices(1, 1); //DataGridColumn Does'nt Inherit Visual class so using GetCellByIndices

        if(cell!=null)
            comboBox = cell.GetVisualChild<ComboBox>(); //DataGridCell Inherit Visual so we can use our VisualHelper Method
    }
```