# Datagrid change image in column with button when event CellEditEnding wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have datagrid. One column is with button:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="WordsDataGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="WordsDataGrid_CellEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="X" Width="10" Binding="{Binding Status}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Visibility="Visible" Height="16" Width="16" Click="Update_Click">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image x:Name="KeyName"  Source="Resources/update.png"  />
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I have other columns with textbox create dynamic in c#.

I want to change image for my button when catch event:

```
private void WordsDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        var column = e.Column.DisplayIndex;
        var row = e.Row.GetIndex();
    }
```

I know row and column but I dont know how to take my button from WordsDataGrid to do:

```
 button.Content = new Image
    {
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Resources/toupdate.png", UriKind.Relative))
    };
```

Edit:

I add

```
Source="{Binding ImageSource}" /> 

public string ImageSource { get; set; } = @"\Resources\update.png";
```

First to xaml, secound to object, and I change string.

Comment: Do you want to do this when you click on the button ?

Comment: No, I want do this when inscribe WordsDataGrid_CellEditEnding. Button is in column index = 6. So when row = 4 I want to take cell for example [4,6] and cast in on button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the `Source` property of the `Button` to a source property of your data object and set this property instead of trying to manipulate the UI elements:

```
private void WordsDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    var index = ...;
    var itemsSource = WordsDataGrid.ItemsSource as IList<YourClass>;
    itemsSource[index].Uri = new Uri(@"/Resources/toupdate.png", UriKind.Relative);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Image x:Name="KeyName"  Source="{Binding Uri}"  />
```

Make sure that YourClass implements INotifyPropertyChanged and raise change notifications.

Answer (score 2):

I you want to do this on click of your button, 
You can use click event of your button :

```
private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  (sender as Button).Content = new Image
  {
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Resources/toupdate.png", UriKind.Relative))
  };
}
```

If from another cell of your datagrid :

[WPF DataGrid: How do I access a ComboBox in a specific row of a DataGridTemplateColumn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255343/wpf-datagrid-how-do-i-access-a-combobox-in-a-specific-row-of-a-datagridtemplate)

Comment: No i dont want. I want do this when update other column.