# Is it possible to refresh only one column in data grid? wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have datagrid connected with database. I have problem with refresh data.
I have 7 column and i use event DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs for column index = 1-5.
Column with index 0 have check box and column with index 6 have button.

Button have image. Which show add/update/toupdate. I need to refresh image in button, after  event DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs and when I click on button. But problem is when I refresh whole datagrid I remove added rows or undoing change. But When I dont refresh it I only refresh button source when I click on this button.

Is it possible to refresh one column? or other solution for my problem?

[image]

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<StatusWords> words = new List<StatusWords>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WordsDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Kategoria", Binding = new Binding("Category"), Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star) });
        WordsDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Mnemonik", Binding = new Binding("Mnemoniese"), Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star) });
        words.Add(new StatusWords() { Category = "A", Mnemoniese = "AA" });
        words.Add(new StatusWords() { Category = "B", Mnemoniese = "BB" });
        words.Add(new StatusWords() { Category = "B", Mnemoniese = "B" });
        WordsDataGrid.ItemsSource = words;
    }
    private void Update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var a = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Button;
        if (WordsDataGrid.SelectedIndex > WordsDataGrid.Items.Count - 2)
            return;

        var index = WordsDataGrid.SelectedIndex;
        var itemsSource = WordsDataGrid.ItemsSource as IList<StatusWords>;
        itemsSource[index].ImageSource = new Uri(@"/Resources/update.png", UriKind.Relative);
        var itemsSource2 = WordsDataGrid.ItemsSource as IList<StatusWords>;
        words[WordsDataGrid.SelectedIndex].ImageSource = new Uri(@"\Resources\update.png", UriKind.Relative);
        var word = words[WordsDataGrid.SelectedIndex] as StatusWords;          
    }
    private void WordsDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        var column = e.Column.DisplayIndex;

        if (column < 1 || column > 5)
            return;
        var row = e.Row.GetIndex();
        var newText = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text;

        if (column == 1)
        {
            words[row].Category = newText;

        }
        if (column == 2 && words[row].Mnemoniese != null && words.Where(x => x.Mnemoniese != null && x.Mnemoniese.ToLower() == newText.ToLower()).Count() > count && words[row].Mnemoniese.ToLower() != newText.ToLower())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name " + newText + " exist");
        }
        else if (column == 2)
        {
            words[row].Mnemoniese = newText;
        }

         words[row].ImageSource = new Uri(@"\Resources\toupdate.png", UriKind.Relative);

        //RefreshDataGridWords();
    }
    private void RefreshDataGridWords()
    {
        WordsDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
        WordsDataGrid.ItemsSource = words;
    }
}
public class StatusWords
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public Uri ImageSource { get; set; } = new Uri(@"\Resources\update.png", UriKind.Relative);       
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Mnemoniese { get; set; }

}
```

And xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="WordsDataGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="WordsDataGrid_CellEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="X" Width="10" Binding="{Binding Status}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Visibility="Visible" Height="16" Width="16" Click="Update_Click">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image x:Name="KeyName"  Source="{Binding ImageSource}"  />
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You refresh a column by setting the property of the data object that is displayed in that column as I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829702/datagrid-change-image-in-column-with-button-when-event-celleditending-wpf).

Comment: It doesnt work. Image isnt change.

Comment: I add image, you can look. Image is the same ;)

Comment: There is no [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for me to look at here I am afraid.

Comment: I add. You only have to add Resources\update.png nad toupdate.png. Change descryption in textbox or click button have to only refresh last column or only one button it cant refresh whole grid.

Comment: Started resources is update.png. When you change data in column Category or Mnemoniese event DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs should change image source on toupdate.png. And click button in data grid should change image on update.png for clicked button.

Comment: You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StatusWords` class where the `ImageSource` property is defined must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the property whenever you set it to a new value:

```
public class StatusWords : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    private Uri _imageSource = new Uri(@"\Resources\update.png", UriKind.Relative);
    public Uri ImageSource
    {
        get { return _imageSource; }
        set { _imageSource = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Mnemoniese { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.